# Mathematics of Indians in America

Tags: education, math-history

Someone could inform me some material of the history of the mathematics of the Indians in America, especially in Brazil. I searched the internet, but I do not find a serious material.
Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately not Brazil but found one link for mathematics of the Incas http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/history/HistTopics/Inca_mathematics.html

Comment: Maybe because there is not anything serious.

Comment: More likely, the serious material is not on the internet, rather books and some journals.

Comment: The Inca civilization had community grain stores and a huge ability to engineer their environment. So I there appears to be a strong link between the rise of great civilizations and the rise of mathematics.

Comment: The University of St. Andrews has an article on [Mayan mathematics](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/Inca_mathematics.html).  The Mayans developed a highly sophisticated calendar through their research in astronomy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The relevant search term is *ethnomathematics*. There are several journals devoted to this topic (for instance, [Revista latinoamericana de etnomatemática](http://www.revista.etnomatematica.org/index.php/RevLatEm)). Browsing them (if you have access to [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/index.html), the relevant MSC class is 01A70) and looking at their references should help you get started.

Another place to look for this is in journals of history of mathematics ([Revista brasileira de história da matemática](http://www.rbhm.org.br/), for example). The (open access) [Journal of humanistic mathematics](http://scholarship.claremont.edu/jhm/) had a paper last year on ethnomodelling you may also find interesting:

> [MR3536482](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3536482). Rosa, Milton; Orey, Daniel Clark. *[Humanizing mathematics through ethnomodelling](http://scholarship.claremont.edu/jhm/vol6/iss2/3/)*. J. Humanist. Math. **6** (2016), no. 2, 3–22.